# string match two character cell arrays and output indices

Tags: matlab

How do you get the indices of the incorrectly classified labels from a cell array of characters. For instance:

```
pred = tt.eval(test_data);
```

I can use the confusion matrix:

```
cm = confusionmat(test_class,pred)
```

However I need the exact indices of misclassifed labels in `pred`. Just an output of the row number of which ones were wrong, based against `test_class`.

Both pred and `test_class` are cell arrays of characters.

For instance:

```
Pred:

1. Normal
2. Normal
3. Normal

test_class:

1. Normal
2. Normal
3. Abnormal
```

Output should be Pred wrongly classified rows:

3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have two cell arrays which contains strings you want to compare?

[strcmp](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) will do the job fine:

```
pred = {'Normal' ; 'Normal' ; 'Normal'};
test_class = {'Normal' ; 'Normal' ; 'Abnormal'};

>> ~strcmp(pred,test_class)

ans =

     0
     0
     1
```

If you want the index numbers, you can use [find](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/find.html) on this previous result:

```
>>find(~strcmp(pred,test_class))

ans =

     3
```

Comment: When I use: `strmtch = strcmp(pred,test_class1);` the output file is just all 1's for some reason. I dont get any 0's, yet my confusion matrix tells me that I have an accuracy of 99.9% so I have some wrong. In your example if row 1 has normal in both pred and test_class then the output should be 0 but I get 1, yet visual inspection of both pred and test_class show the exact same class labels for atleast first 15 or so that I can see.

Comment: `strcmp` compares the rows, if the strings are identical, output is 1, if not, output is 0. Please read the documentation of the link I provided in the solution.

Comment: Then the answer would be 1,1,0 not 0,0,1 in your example. Which would then output rows 1 and 2 but not 3 in your find method. Which is the problem I get.

Comment: all right all right, I forgot the `~` in the second code with `find`, fixed ^^